# Export paginated mat-table with Angular Material Table Exporter

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to export a mat-table as excel using MatTable Exporter but I am getting an error:

> Can't bind to 'cdkTable' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-table'.

component.html

```html
<button mat-raised-button color="primary" #exportButton>export</button>

<mat-table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" #mytable [cdkTable]="mytable" class="mat-elevation-z8" [hidden]="!dataSource" ngxMatTableExporter [exporterButton]="exportButton" sheetName="ss" fileName="ff">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="OrderId">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Order Id</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.OrderId}}</td>
    </ng-container>
</mat-table>
```

in module.ts

```js
import { CdkTableModule } from '@angular/cdk/table';
import { MatTableModule,MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [OrderComponent],
  imports: [
    CdkTableModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatTableModule,
  ] 
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to import MatTableExporterModule.
Check this stackblitz out: https://stackblitz.com/edit/mte-demo

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatTableExporterModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatFormFieldModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 2):

Although this is an old post, this might help if you're using an older version of Angular versus a newer version.

Depending on what version of Angular you are using, if you have 8 or older:

```
npm install --save mat-table-exporter@1.2.5
```

Otherwise, use the following:

```
npm install --save mat-table-exporter
```

Once installed, add the import to the module you need it for:

```
import { MatTableExporterModule } from 'mat-table-exporter';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ..,
    MatTableExporterModule
  ]
})
export class NameModule { }
```